# Loading related entities with JDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

In a Spring Web Api I'm using JDBC (mandatory) to load the data from DB. I have for example, a Student that have an list for the Classes that are in, also I have a Class that have a list with the Students in it.

Then when I load the Class, for example, I have a method to load related entities (one of which is Student), but doing this way will also load the related of Student (with Class in it) and it will get into a loop.

Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Look something named `Lazy Loading`.